# Add to homepage and reorder

Tags: channel-entries, low-reorder

I am trying to find the most common way to add entries to the home page and then reorder them.

In the past I have set a custom status and used Low Reorder to sort the entries.

Are there other methods people prefer?

I have tested https://bitbucket.org/ajweaver/ajw_selecteditems/src but it hasn't been updated in a while and also throwing an error in EE 2.6 so i'm hesistant to use it.

Appreciate any thoughts.

N

Comment: Did any of the answers below do the trick for you ?

Answer (score 3):

Various approaches for such things. Here are my favorites:

Create a homepage channel with one entry and as many custom fields as you need. You could use a Playa or a relationship field to select and order the entries you want on the homepage. [Approach detailed by Leevi Graham on GitHub](https://github.com/leevigraham/expressionengine-fundamentals/blob/master/chapters/03-homepage.md)

Using [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables), make a bunch of variables to control your homepage. Create a Playa, Relationship variable for the entries you want to order on your homepage. Alternatively, you can also use the [select entries variable type](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/docs/types#select-entries) bundled with Low Variables.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the new [relationship field](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html).

Since now it's possible to select several entries and reorder them, you can have a relationship field for your home page. You can use the Pages Module to make a homepage setting its URL to '/', or you can create a Channel for homepages. Both ways, you can have relationship fields to select and reorder the chosen entries.